# Video Player inside CollectionView item addition causes video frame shuffle Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, avplayer, collectionview

I have a `CollectionView` that has a `VideoPlayer` element in its `DataTemplate` taken from [Xamarin Forms sample projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/customrenderers-videoplayerdemos/). On iOS, the video player rendered uses `AVPlayer` to play video.
I also have a button that when pressed, adds more items to the `ItemSource` of the `CollectionView`.
If I play the first, say, three items and pause them all on random frame/time, and then press this add more items button, the frozen image frames on these three `AVPlayer` instances on iPhone get shuffled/switched in some weird order.
In more detail:

If the first item of the `CollectionView` has some animated cartoon video paused, and the second item has some sports game video paused, and the third item has some forest images video paused, when I press the add more items button, and some new items get added to the `ItemSource` of the `CollectionView`, I see the sports game video frame moved to the first item's `AVPlayer` instance, the forest images video frame moved to second item's `AVPlayer` instance and the animated cartoon frame is moved to third item's `AVPlayer` instance. To clarify: the items themselves stay in their exact position, only the video frames in AVPlayer are switched.

After these have been 'shuffled', if I unpause the first item, it plays its original video of animated cartoon, and same goes with item two and three. The only problem, as I understand it, is that somewhere in the caching / cell reusing mechanism of `CollectionView`, the cached frames of `AVPlayer` are switched in some order when new items are added to the `CollectionView`.
This problem happens exclusively with `AVPlayer`. Any other element, does not reproduce this behavior. I have tried with ffimageloading's `CahcedImage`, simple labels and other elements, but it is only `AVPlayer's` rendered, paused frame images that get shuffled.
I realize this issue probably has some deep roots that won't be solved on Xamarin Forms level, but just wanted to try my luck here.

My code for the CollectionView is pretty basic:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ScrollArticles}" 

                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
        RemainingItemsThreshold="5"
                RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding LoadMoreItems}"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                ItemsLayout="VerticalList"
                x:Name="CategoryItemsListView"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                Scrolled="CategoryItemsListView_OnScrolled"

                >

    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

                <elements:VideoPlayer Margin="0,0,0,15" Source={Binding video_url}>

                </elements:VideoPlayer>

        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

The same exact code, when having the `VideoPlayer` element replaced with any other element, say `Image`, behaves as it should.
Another thing is that the same exact `VideoPlayer` code does not do this when implemented inside `ListView` (with `CachingStrategy=RecycleElement`) instead of `CollectionView`. But unfortunately, `ListView` lacks a lot of features such as determining the center most item when scrolling etc.

Comment: Can you please share us your test project? I tried to reproduce the issue on my side but I  failed.

Comment: Hi, I will try to do so once I finish my current project. Unfortunately due to deadline considerations I was forced to switch to ListView that does not have the same bug for the same exact code.

Comment: OK, I will check once you have time to share a test project:).